# Haskell, Parsec - Parsing application in lambda calculus

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I am writing a simple parser/interpreter for lambda calculus in Haskell.

I am using the syntax "/(x.x)" for a lambda function, "x" for a name and "f y" for application, such that "/(x.x) y" is the application of identity to y and should return y.

My strategy is to have a parser for names, lambda functions and applications. The name and function parsers work, but not the application parser.

When I try to parse "/(x.x) y" it fails. It should try to parse the source as a name, as a lambda function, and after not being able to use both (because it would not parse all the source) try to parse it as an application and then succeed.

My code is:

```
module Main where

import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

data Expression =
  Var String
  | Lambda Expression Expression
  | Application Expression Expression
  deriving Eq

instance Show Expression where
  show (Var v) = v
  show (Lambda v e) = "/(" ++ show v ++ "." ++ show e ++ ")"
  show (Application e1 e2) = "" ++ show e1 ++ " " ++ show e2 ++ ""

-- Parser

parseSource :: String -> Expression
parseSource source =
  case parse (parseExpression <* eof) "" source of
    Right e -> e
    _ -> error "Parsing error"

parseExpression :: Parser Expression
parseExpression =
  parseVar <|> parseLambda <|> parseApplication

parseVar :: Parser Expression
parseVar = Var <$> many1 letter

parseLambda :: Parser Expression
parseLambda = do
  _ <- char '/'
  _ <- char '('
  arg <- parseVar
  _ <- char '.'
  body <- parseExpression
  _ <- char ')'
  return $ Lambda arg body

parseApplication :: Parser Expression
parseApplication = do
  e1 <- parseExpression
  _ <- spaces
  e2 <- parseExpression
  return $ Application e1 e2
```

Comment: The problem is that an `Application` will parse as some single `Expression` plus some leftover. You could instead parse per single `Expression` and then combine it into (left-associated) `Application`s: ```parseExpression = foldl1 Application <$> (parseLambda <|> parseVar) `sepBy1` spaces```